# Python regex: how to replace each instance of an occurrence with a different value?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have this string:
`s = "blah blah blah"`

Using Python regex, how can I replace each instance of "blah" with a different value (e.g. I have a list of values `v = ("1", "2", "3")`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a [`re.sub` callback](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
def callback(match):
    return next(callback.v)
callback.v=iter(('1','2','3'))

s = "blah blah blah"
print(re.sub(r'blah',callback,s))
```

yields

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: Adding the iterable to the function as an attribute is a really nice approach.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.

Comment: a closure would be way saner.

Answer (score 13):

You could use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), which takes a string or function and applies it to each match:

```
>>> re.sub('blah', lambda m, i=iter('123'): next(i), 'blah blah blah')
<<< '1 2 3'
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't need regex:

```
s.replace("blah","%s")%v
```

the replace produces "%s %s %s", then you use the format operator

Comment: As long as `s` does not contain `%`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't really need a regex.

```
for x in v:
  s = s.replace('blah', x, 1)
```

However if you really wanted a regex:

```
import re
for x in v:
  s = re.sub('blah', x, s, count=1)
```

Comment: I see two problems with this: 1) It's inefficient, because each call to `.replace` starts searching for an occurence to replace at the start of the string. 2) It straight up doesn't work if `v` contains the word "blah".