# Python Regex: words between two delimiters - replace leading delimiters with punctuation, but removing ending ones

Tags: python, regex

```
test_str = '**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James'
```

expected output:

```
output: Amount: $25k, Name: James
```

I can only use re.sub function to remove/replace delimiters **words** but cannot get the expected result.

Also, is it possible to generalize the code to implement on all delimiters (**xx**, < xx>, etc)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service, and it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you (why else would you only be allowed to use `re.sub`?) If you're going to ask a question on SO, please follow the guidelines on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I believe most of people post questions on stack overflow is either for their work or study. I already researched a lot of resources and attempted a lot ways but could figure out. According to your saying, people should stop posting anything on stack overflow unless it is unrelated to work or study.

Comment: My point is that you didn't follow the How to Ask guidelines when posting this question. I mentioned that it sounded like you were asking us to do your homework for you as a side point. You still haven't updated your question according to the How to Ask guidelines, even though you've found the time to reply to me?

Comment: You're very engaged with me! I read the guidelines and didn't see anything inappropriate for my post: First, I wrote a title that summarizes the specific problem; second, I introduced the problem before posting codes; third, helping others reproduce the problem by asking how to generalize it to other delimiters; fourth,  include all relevant tags: python, regex; fifth, proof-read before posting; last, post the question and respond to feedback. Feel free to report me to admin, I don't see I did anything violate the guidelines.

Comment: You haven't done the one thing I asked: show us what you've tried. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. It's easier for us to work with what you've tried and show you where it doesn't work, and then offer alternatives. It's ballsy to ask us to do the codewriting for you.

Comment: @Joel I mentioned I used re.sub function which is my initial try. If you really like barking in public, go to dog park instead. Other people already used their vote and answers ruthlessly slapped your face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach using `re.sub`. First `re.sub` removes `*`, second `re.sub` adds commas:

```
import re

test_str = '**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James'

s = re.sub(r'\s*([^:\s]+)\s*:\s*([^\s]+)', r'\1: \2, ', re.sub(r'[\*\s]+', ' ', test_str)).rstrip(', ')
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Amount: $25k, Name: James
```

With *, <, > as delimiters:

```
test_str = '**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James <<Name2>> : Another <Name3> : Jack'

s = re.sub(r'\s*([^:\s]+)\s*:\s*([^\s]+)', r'\1: \2, ', re.sub(r'[\*<>\s]+', ' ', test_str)).rstrip(', ')
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Amount: $25k, Name: James, Name2: Another, Name3: Jack
```

Comment: thanks Andrej! that's a very appealing answer! If I understand your code correctly, this part: re.sub(r'[\*<>\s]+', ' ', test_str) is to remove delimiters from test_str; r'\s*([^:\s]+)\s*:\s*([^\s]+)' captures the pattern; r'\1: \2, ' add punctuation to the string.

Comment: @user92654 Yes, this will substitute all `*`, `<`. `>` and whitespaces (multiple)  with " ".

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
st='**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James'

stage1=re.sub(r"\**","",st)

re.sub(r'(?<=\:\s\S\S\S\S\s)',",",stage1)
```

The output will be

```
'Amount : $25k , Name : James'
```

to match regex you must look at the online regex testers like [this one](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: remove asterisk is easy task but add punctuation is actual challenging for this one

Comment: @user92654 there will be further conditions I am sure see if it works for all of your needs

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`, simply fill in the first argument with the delimiters you want to remove. `[*<>]` contains `*`, `<`, and `>` but you can populate it with any values that are needed.

```
re.sub('[*<>]','', test_str)
'Amount : $25k  Name : James'
```

**Edit**

I will in no way claim to have invented this method [(credit to @unutbu)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293794/9435107) but it should work for any number of key-value pairs.

```
def callback(match):
   return next(callback.v)
key_val_count =  test_str.count(':') - 1
len_of_keys = key_val_count * ('',',')
callback.v = iter(('',*len_of_keys ,''))
print (re.sub('([*<>]+)',callback, test_str))
Amount : $25k  ,Name : James
```

Comment: i think challenging about this is how to remove only ending delimiters, but replace lending ones with punctuation so it will benefit following negation strip. so it could look like    Amount : $25k,  Name : James

Answer (score 0):

One regex but with lambda:

```
re.sub(r"\*|\s(?=:)|(?<=\d)k\s*",lambda m:"k, " if "k" in m.group() else "",test_str)
'Amount: $25k, Name: James'
```